# LinQ query group the same table twice

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I need some help.
**The problem**: I have `User` and a `MedalTransaction` class.
A user can assign medals and receive them as well. `MedalTransaction` has 2 properties called `Origin` and `Destination` that are User Id's.

---

**What I've tried:**

```
var q = (from user in companyUsers
         join mt in Context.MedalTransactions
         on user.Id equals mt.Destination into medalTransactions

         from mt in medalTransactions.DefaultIfEmpty()

         group new { user, mt } by new { mt.Destination } into receivedMedals

         select new User
         {
             Id = receivedMedals.Select(u => u.user.Id).FirstOrDefault(),
             Name = receivedMedals.Select(u => u.user.Name).FirstOrDefault(),
             Company = receivedMedals.Select(u => u.user.Company).FirstOrDefault(),

             TotalAcquiredMedals = receivedMedals
                .Where(m => m.mt.Destination == m.user.Id && m.mt.Origin != systemId)
                .Sum(m => m.mt.Quantity)                       

         })
        .OrderByDescending(u => u.TotalAcquiredMedals);
```

---

This works, **but only for the acquired medals**.
I wanted to set the other property `TotalAssignedMedals` on the user instance creation.
I have tried multiple `group by` but never got the results I wanted, I don't even know if it is possible to do this.

Thank you for your help

---

**EDIT**
**Question solved, final code:**

```
var q = (from user in companyUsers

                 join mt in Context.MedalTransactions
                 on user.Id equals mt.Destination into receivedMedals

                 join mt2 in Context.MedalTransactions
                 on user.Id equals mt2.Origin into assignedMedals

                 from mtReceived in receivedMedals.DefaultIfEmpty()
                 from mtAssigned in assignedMedals.DefaultIfEmpty()

                 group new { user, mtReceived, mtAssigned } by new { user.Id } into medalTransactions

                 select new User
                 {
                     Id = medalTransactions.Select(_ => _.user.Id).FirstOrDefault(),
                     Name = medalTransactions.Select(_ => _.user.Name).FirstOrDefault(),
                     Company = medalTransactions.Select(_ => _.user.Company).FirstOrDefault(),

                     TotalAcquiredMedals = medalTransactions
                        .DistinctBy(m => m.mtReceived.Id)
                        .Where(m => m.mtReceived.Origin != systemId)
                        .Sum(m => m.mtReceived.Quantity),

                     TotalAssignedMedals = medalTransactions
                        .DistinctBy(m => m.mtAssigned.Id)
                        .Where(m => m.mtAssigned.Destination != systemId)
                        .Sum(m => m.mtAssigned.Quantity)

                 })
                .OrderByDescending(u => u.TotalAcquiredMedals);
```

Comment: Try using a Where user.receiveMedals == mt.receivedMedals

Comment: @jdweng The user does not have a navigation property to MedalTransaction, I can't do that unfortunately.
But maybe I should add it, I will leave that option on the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe something like that

```
from user in companyUsers

join mt in Context.MedalTransactions
on user.Id equals mt.Destination into destinations

join mt2 in Context.MedalTransactions
on user.Id equals mt2.Origin into origins

from mtd in mt.DefaultIfEmpty()
from mto in mt2.DefaultIfEmpty()

group new { user, mtd, mto } by new { user.Id } into medals
select new {user.Id, user.Name, ..., 
    TotalAcquiredMedals = mtd.Where(_ => _ != null).Distinct().Count(), 
    TotalAssignedMedals = mto.Where(_ => _ != null).Distinct().Count()
}
```

Comment: After some minor changes I implemented your suggestion and it worked.
Thanks!